# Prove the right hand limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-verification

Given f(x) = $\frac{|x|}{x}$. We need to prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+} = 1$.

Based on the definition of the right hand limit, we need to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta$ such that $\forall x$: $0$ < $x$ < $\delta$, we have |$\frac{|x|}{x}$ - 1| < $\epsilon$

Since x is in the domain larger than $0$, so I can conclude that $\frac{|x|}{x} = 1$. Thus, 0 < $\epsilon$. So I prove this statement. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, but.... you know that $x > 0$, so get $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {|x|}x = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac xx =\lim_{x\to 0^+}1$ out of the *immediately*.  Now, do you *really* need to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1 = 1$?  If so *now* we can natter on about formally proving it with $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s if we need to but all (unnecessary) heavy lifting has been taken care of.

Comment: Actually, if *you* are going to bring up that you are going to do a $\delta$ $\epsilon$ proof then *I* am going to ask for details.  What is the $\delta$ you used for proving if $x - 0 < \delta$ then $|f(x)-1| < \epsilon$ and how did you conclude $|f(x)-1| = 0$.  Technically speaking we already *knew* $0 < \epsilon$.  What we *didn't* know was $|f(x)-1| =0$...I'm being nitpicky and silly and had you just said "If $x > 0$ then $|x|=x$ and $\frac {|x|}x=1$ so $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} 1 = 1$", I wouldn't have asked for *anything*, but... well, if you bring up $\delta$, $\epsilon$...

Comment: You got the idea; the writing of the proof can be improved though. 

For any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\epsilon$ (any positive number here would work). Then, for all $x$ with $0<x<\delta$, 
$$
|f(x)-1|=|1-1|=0<\epsilon.
$$